# Toggle Switch Internet Connection - Between Two Computers

Tags: router, internet, ethernet, switch, hub

I have regular cable internet.

I also have a personal computer and work computer in my residence.

I would like to toggle share internet, so if personal home computer is using internet, work computer cannot. If work computer is using internet, home computer cannot.
Should I utilize with ethernet cable

(a) router

(b) splitter

(c) hub

(d) switch ?

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you need that? It's a rather unusual requirement.

Comment: You need "managed switch". You can disable/enable on demand Ethernet ports

Comment: can you post as answer? maybe little better than first answer below, thanks-

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to be asking for is called an "A/B box".

For ethernet you want the "RJ45" version

Comment: If an A/B switch is implemented, it is important to note that it may be necessary to power-off or otherwise reset the cable modem each time the switch is moved. Some cable modem devices will not make connection when a "dead-swap" is made in this manner. It is the equivalent of pulling the cable free from one computer and inserting it in the second. In my experience, it usually requires a modem restart. That's an additional level of inconvenience.

Comment: yeah, how well this will work it depends on whether  "regular cable internet" provides a router or just a modem.  if there's a router the newly switched computer will see a new ethernet connection, and sort itself out using DHCP